# Getting multiple footnotes on the same line with gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I've got the following reprex

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

set.seed(50)

dat <- data.frame(exposed = sample(c("Unexposed","Exposed"), 100, TRUE),
                  year = rep(c(1985,1986), each = 50),
                  Age = rnorm(100, 85, 1),
                  Transit = sample(c("Bus", "Train", "Walk", "Car"), 100, TRUE))

dat %>%
  tbl_strata(strata = year,
             ~ .x %>%
               tbl_summary(
                 by = exposed,
                 include = c(Age, Transit),
                 statistic = list(Age ~ "{mean} ± {sd}"),
                 digits = Age ~ 1,
                 label = Age ~ "Age, mean ± SD"
               )) %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**") %>%
  modify_footnote(update = everything() ~ NA)
```

which produces this table:

[image]

but when I try to add a new, separate footnote, the previous one gets overwritten

```
dat %>%
  tbl_strata(strata = year,
             ~ .x %>%
               tbl_summary(
                 by = exposed,
                 include = c(Age, Transit),
                 statistic = list(Age ~ "{mean} ± {sd}"),
                 digits = Age ~ 1,
                 label = Age ~ "Age, mean ± SD"
               )) %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**") %>%
  modify_table_styling(columns = label,
                       rows = variable == "Age",
                       footnote = "Footnote 1") %>%
  modify_table_styling(columns = label,
                       rows = label == "Transit",
                       footnote = "Footnote 2") %>%
  modify_table_styling(columns = label,
                       rows = label == "Transit",
                       footnote = "Footnote 3") %>%
  modify_footnote(update = everything() ~ NA)
```

and my table looks like this.

[image]

I've tried using modify_footnote as described [here](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify.html) but I don't understand the documentation for how to get the footnotes out of the columns and into the rows.

The final output should look something like this.

[image]

Comment: gtsummary only allows one footnote per cell. to add more, first convert your table to gt with `as_gt()`, then use the gt functions to add more footnotes.